# Confusion as to function parameters

Tags: python, function, scope, interactive

I am trying to make a simple function that accepts 2 parameters, and adds them together using "+".

```
def do_plus (a,b):
    a=3
    b=7
    result = a + b
    print (result)
```

However, I get no value returned, the function is executed but no output is shown.

Comment: `return result` and you also need to call the function e.g. `my_calculation = do_plus(3, 7)` outside of the function. There's no point giving hard-coded values to `a` and `b` inside the function, you want to pass them as _arguments_. Also, everything that's supposed to be inside the function should be indented.

Comment: `from operator import add as do_plus`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the indentation.

```
a=3
b=7
def do_plus (a,b):
    result =a+b
    print (result)
# and you have to call the function:
do_plus(a,b)
```

You probably want to separate logic from input/output, as so:

```
def do_plus(a, b):
    result = a + b
    return result

res = do_plus(3, 7)
print(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
def do_plus (a,b):
    print=a+b
do_plus(3, 7)
```

you can call your function "do_plus" passing parameters and print wath the function return

Attention to the "spaces" before result is important in python the identation of script

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell from your code because the indentation is off, but a simple addition function can be something like:

```
def addition(a, b):
  return a + b
```

You are accepting parameters `a` and `b`, but then assigning them values `7` and `3`, so that no matter what, it will return `10`.

Comment: `addition(5,None)` ?